# Using command line arguments inside of EOF

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am attempting to create a rather simple script that zcats a gzipped file into an sqlite3 database.

prototype:

```
sh myscript.sh filename dbname tablename
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
zcat $1 > tmpfile
sqlite3 $2 <<'EOF'
.separator "\t"
.import tmpfile $3
EOF
```

The problem is that when my import occurs, the table name is the literal "$3" instead of the desired contents of the 3rd argument.

Please show me how to do this. Bonus points for teaching me the vocabulary that I must be missing in order to find this.

I tried a bunch of search variations of the following, to no avail:

- "Command line argument literal within EOF"
- "Passing command line argument within EOF"

Comment: See [Variable not interpreted with 'EOF'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379580/variable-not-interpreted-with-eof)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for that!